# why I cant read a file to an integer vector?

Tags: c++, vector, file-io

well! I have a text file including some integer values and non-integers like character strings and white spaces so I want only to read integers values so I used a vector of integers but when I read the file the opining is ok but it seems the first input fails thus breaks the loop!!!

here is my main example:

```
ifstream in("file.txt");
if(in.fail())
    cout << "opening failed!" << endl;
//opening is fine!

int value;
vector<int> v;

while(in >> value) // the problem here; it fails why?
{
    cout << "ok"; // not printed
    v.push_back(value);
}

cout << v.size() << endl; // 0??!!
```

this is the content of file.txt:

```
32 43 24 32
15 23
57
77 81
```

if I make a vector of chars it's ok but I want only to use one of integers

*** I already used a code like this and worked fine but now I don't know what happened??!!! it's really annoting

any help, comment, tip is welcome and appreciated

Comment: It works on my system. But you should definitely check, if the opening of the file worked: `if(!in)`

Comment: yes it is opened. I checked. one thing I doubt: `does this belong to compiler some messing up??`

Comment: I doubt it, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using msvc++ 15

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: @yassin: thanks a lot I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 while(in >> value)
```

says while I can read integers...

But in the post this may not be true - you are not handling this case.

Either read stuff that is not integers and handle it. Or just read strings and then decide what to do.

In addition

```
 cout << "ok"; // not printed
```

is because it is buffered.

Do this

```
cout << "ok" << flush; // printed
```

Comment: but my file has integers separated by spaces and even adding `flush` nothing happens??!!

Comment: Have you checked if you have opened the file?

Comment: Guess my eyesight is getting bad as that is not posted in the code

Comment: yes I checked and the opening was ok. does it belong to some system configuration or something like that?

Comment: it works there but on my computer already about 2 months works and now it doesn't!!! it is really embarrassing.

Comment: Please copy'n'paste my code to you computer. Get that to run. Then change `cin` to a file

Comment: thank you very much!  I managed to figure it out. the answer is below.

Comment: do you think this issue is important?

Comment: It was important to you. To me - does not matter

Comment: because you didn't unintentionally get caught by the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

excuse me first for annoying you with nonsense question. finally I managed to discover the error:

in my main folder of project I unintentionally created a winrar file `input.rar` then I didn't remove it but rename it to `input.txt` it's ok I opened it manually and removed some unreadable characters. then I put inside it the content above of integers then my c++ application succeeds in opening it but can't read it.
 *now I removed it `input.txt` which was `input.rar` and created a new document text `input.txt` and now everything is good!!!

thank you for your collaboration. and this post may help someone else.
* don't create `rar` file or other formats then rename them to be text files and try to read them via your c++ fstream because it'll fail in fact it'll produce an error-prone which looks impossible to solve